# How to convert 15-Oct-14 varchar to datetime format 2014-10-23 00:00:00.000

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have tried many combinations i want to convert my Date which is imported from excel and is stored as varchar in 15-Oct-14 format, what i want is to convert it to MSSqlserver datetime format 2014-10-23 00:00:00.000 i have tried all combination from http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx but nothing is working for me.

Comment: What about substring?

Comment: convert(datetime,'15-Oct-14')

Comment: SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATETIME, '15-oct-14', 103 )

Comment: After import null was stored as string that is why I was getting error, anyways thanks for  help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the below script and hope this suits your requirement:

```
Set dateformat ymd
Select convert(datetime,'15-Oct-14',105)
```

Comment: Getting error -Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @SachinPrasad: It is running fine at my end. Can you re-check the script you are using?

Comment: first line i.e. 'Set dateformat ymd' is not needed. Second line Works fine without it.

Comment: @Satyajit: I have used first line to make sure that result should be in YMD format coz it may happen that system is not set to YMD by default.

Comment: I have tried with changing the format value to 'dmy' i.e. 
Set dateformat dmy; But the output remains same. So, want to know if these line plays any role in the next statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (solution with guard):

```
set dateformat YMD;

select
  case
    when isdate(date_column) = 1 then convert(date, date_column, 105)
  end [converted_date]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select cast('15-Oct-14' as datetime)
```